# Access Upload Data Error

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have a form on MS Access, where I am trying to upload an excel spreadsheet into the database.

It has been working for other spreadsheets, but for some reason I am trying to upload data into a table, and I continue to get the error:

"you cannot record changes because a value you entered violates the settings defined for this table or list (for example, a value is less than the minimum or greater than the maximum). correct the error and try again"

Can someone explain to me why I am getting this error, and how to fix it?

I have already made sure that:
- In the access table, there are no "required" fields
- The appropriate data type is associated to the field

Comment: Are you trying to enter a string in a number field? Or something like that?

Comment: Nope. I have the number fields matched up with numbers, and strings with either Short/Long text. I even tried to use the Short/Long text as the data type for all of the fields in access, still doesn't work

Comment: So the table already exists in the database before the import? Sounds like you may have a 'Validation Rule' for one or more fields? Is the table related to other tables? Possibly import the sheet into a new table, then try to append the rows to your existing table. Should show the rows that fails?

Comment: Excellent suggestion, worked like a charm. Thanks a ton!!! @WayneG.Dunn